# PhalconPHP create tables dynamically

Tags: php, database, orm, phalcon

Using PhalconPHP, is it possible to create a table in a database using an ORM model with metadata in comments? For example, using symphony one can achive what I want like this: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

so the solution I've found is this

```
$connection->createTable("robots", null, array(
      "columns" => array(
            new Column("id", array(
                "type"  => Column::TYPE_INTEGER,
                "size"  => 10,
                "notNull"       => true,
                "autoIncrement" => true,
            )),
            new Column("name", array(
                "type"    => Column::TYPE_VARCHAR,
                "size"    => 70,
                "notNull" => true,
            )),
            new Column("year", array(
                "type"    => Column::TYPE_INTEGER,
                "size"    => 11,
                "notNull" => true,
            ))
      ),
      "indexes" => array(
            new Index("PRIMARY", array("id"))
      )
));
```

hope it will be help to someone :)